# FB Like Count Not showing

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like

I realise this has been listed a million times and I can't seem to find one that matches mine...

Not great on Java so using the html5 version - installed the SDK and they can be seen in source but not rendering.

The difference is that the like count is in relation to a different page so we have a page with lots of like counts on it for different video's referring to another page that holds all the og: requirements for that video..

[www.hdrctv.com](http://www.hdrctv.com)

page with a bunch of video's that are then linked to there respective video's.

Now strangely for a brief second I did see it working then I refreshed that page and they went and I've been hammering away at this for hours trying to work out why its not working.

Head Has

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1074088679397725" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="HDRCtv"/>
```

Body has

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1074088679397725',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(){
     // If we've already installed the SDK, we're done
     if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}

     // Get the first script element, which we'll use to find the parent node
     var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

     // Create a new script element and set its id
     var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
     facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';

     // Set the new script's source to the source of the Facebook JS SDK
     facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

     // Insert the Facebook JS SDK into the DOM
     firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(facebookJS, firstScriptElement);
   }());
</script>
```

Then its called with

```
<fb:like href="{seourl rewrite="video/`$answers[i].VID`" url="view_video.php?viewkey=`$answers[i].vkey`" clean=$answers[i].title}" send="true" width="100" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Had to edit my original post not allowed to do a full reply for 8hrs :-(

Comment: Really stumped on this one - anyone have any suggestions

Comment: did it - not sure how but after ton's of trial and error found a working solution.